# How Do I Hide Rows Unless There Are 2 Rows Per Group in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I've created a view that shows families with children that are enrolled in multiple programs in our agency. We only need to see when there are two children in two different programs but the same family. When bringing this view into Reporting Services, how do I only show when there are two rows per group and hide the rest? For example, if the Smith family has two children - one in Head Start and the other in Early Head Start - how do I show those rows but hide the others that only list one child per family?

Currently, I have two CASE statements in the SQL code. One creates a column that displays a 1 for every occurrence of the Head Start program term and a 0 otherwise. The other does the same thing but for every occurrence of the Early Head Start program term.

I've tried going a different route and condensing both of these CASE statements into one column, grouping them by the Family Name, and counting the 1's per family. However, this doesn't give us the detailed data we need; we need to show each child's name and program term.

I've been experimenting with both CountRows expressions in the Row Visibility section of SSRS and IIF statements in the report tablix, but I can't get either to work.

SQL CODE:

```
SELECT CP_Data.dbo.Family.FamilyName,
       CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.PersonName,
       CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.ChildPlusID,
       CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.EnrlStatus,
       CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.ProgramTermAbbreviation,
       CASE WHEN ProgramTermAbbreviation = 'HS20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HSIdentifier,
       CASE WHEN ProgramTermAbbreviation = 'EH20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EHSIdentifier,
       CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.EnrollmentDate
FROM CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CP_Data.dbo.FamilyMembership ON CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.ParticipantPersonID = CP_Data.dbo.FamilyMembership.PersonID
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN CP_Data.dbo.Family ON CP_Data.dbo.FamilyMembership.FamilyID = CP_Data.dbo.Family.FamilyID
WHERE (CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.ProgramTermAbbreviation = 'HS20'
    OR CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.ProgramTermAbbreviation = 'EH20')
  AND (CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.EnrlStatus = 'Enrolled'
    OR CP_Data.dbo.vParticipant.EnrlStatus LIKE 'Drop%');
```

In the end, I want the report to list only the families that have a child in both programs and hide the rest. Should I re-do my CASE statements or implement a line of code in the Row Visibility setting for SSRS? Currently, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Referencing columns with 3+ part naming (you're using 4 here) is deprecated and should be avoided. You should *really* being using aliases here and it'll make your SQL vastly easier to read. it's vastly bloated out with all those 4 part references to columns. Personally, something like [this](https://pastebin.com/26CkCR83) is far more readable.

Comment: That mix of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins is quite odd too.

Comment: @Larnu I used the Design view to join the tables together and it automatically added the 4-part naming convention. As for the left and right joins, I'm attempting to get the relevant data from both the vParticipant table and the Family table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use the `RowVisibility` to hide the rows that do not meet your criteria.  First, I would suggest potentially using the [`OVER` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get a single field that will identify those `FamilyName` groups that have one(or more) child in each program.

```
SELECT...
SUM(CASE WHEN ProgramTermAbbreviation = 'HS20' OR ProgramTermAbbreviation = 'EH20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY FamilyName) AS HSIdentifier
```

From there, you can set the `RowVisibility` to hidden when the value is 1 or less.  It looks to me like the easiest way to do this would be an expression like the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!HSIdentifier.Value > 1, false, true)
```

If I understand the way your data works, this should give you the exact result you're hoping for, but let me know if I misunderstood something.